# File Download headless: false, but not saved

Tags: puppeteer

I am able to initiate a download by clicking on the download and can see download start in headless but file is not saved.

```
function setDownloadBehavior(downloadPath='./') {
    return page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
        behavior: 'allow',
        downloadPath
    });
 }

  await setDownloadBehavior();

  await page.mouse.click(644, 288
  );
```

Here is the download code I am using. Would appreciate any feedbacks.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refrain from posting screenshots of your code, this is not productive for other users. Please post your actual code here.

Comment: Revised the post

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute path for `downloadPath`: some OSs do not support relative paths here. You can use [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname), for example.

Comment: I see the download is being saved to my downloads folder in Windows. I have created a debian server installed node and set the download path to (downloadPath='./)
Still download is not saved. 

I also found out that the download opens in a new tab to be saved. May be that is the issue?